# how to iterate through this value?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 var s=  [{"id":"1","deleted":"0","data":[{"title":"Business Unit","value":"bus 1"},{"title":"Company ID","value":"comp 1"},{"title":"Parent ID","value":"parent 1"},{"title":"NPI","value":"npi 1"}]}];
```

i want to display in a table?

Comment: Actually i want to iterate through this array. How will I do that? By doingJSON.stringify I am not able to loop the array

Comment: you need to access s.data[0].title, s.data[0].value, s.data[1].title, s.data[1].value...  etc...

Comment: https://mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/  this explains the basic ideas

Answer (score -1):

Your `variable s` is an array which contains one single element which is an object.

```
var s = [{}]
```

I see you have the `"data"` key inside the single object, whose value is an array:

```
"data": [{
        "title": "Business Unit",
        "value": "bus 1"
    }, {
        "title": "Company ID",
        "value": "comp 1"
    }, {
        "title": "Parent ID",
        "value": "parent 1"
    }, {
        "title": "NPI",
        "value": "npi 1"
    }]
```

To **iterate over arrays** (this is what you are asking for in your comment), you can use:

1. [for...of statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

i.e.

```
for (const element of s[0]['data']) {
  console.log('title', element.title);  // will output 'Business Unit' for first element
  console.log('value', element.value);  // will output 'bus 1' for first element
}
```

2. [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

i.e.

```
s.forEach(element => console.log(element)); 
// will output the single object contained in var s. 
// You can access each key with dot or bracket notation (element[id]) or (element.id)
```

To **iterate over an object keys and values**, you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method.
i.e.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(s[0])) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  // First line will be: id: 1
}
```

I also advice you to check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for any doubt regarding JavaScript.